# How can I increment array values in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a program that "encodes" text basically by bumping the character by 1. So abc becomes bcd, for example. I am trying to figure out how to have it use array values of -5, 8, 12, 6, 1 instead of 1. I am stuck at 'prompt[i]++;' This bumps letters by 1. How would I use the array values instead here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

  string secret1;
  cout << "Enter name of file to decode: "<< endl;
  cin >> secret1;
  fstream one;
  one.open (secret1);
  if(!one.good()) throw "I/O error";

  string secret2 = "secret.txt";
  ofstream fout;
  fout.open("secret.txt"); //overwrite document


  const int SIZE = 5; //array
  int offset[SIZE] = {-5, 8, 12, 6, 1}; //array values
  int counter = 0;
    while (true)
    {  
     if (!one.good()) break;

     one >> secret1;
     string prompt = secret1;
     int index = counter % SIZE;
     for (int i = 0; i < prompt.length(); i++) // for each char in the 
     string...

     prompt[i]++; // bumps the ASCII code by 1

     ofstream fout;
     fout.open(secret2, ios::app);
     fout << prompt << endl;
    }
  one.close();
  fout.close();
}
```

Comment: you should fix your code formatting. There is a comment reaching into the next line and there is indentation missing, making it very difficult to read.

Comment: your question would be easier to read if you replace "bump" with "increment"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To increment by arbitrary value, replace `++` (which always increments by one) with `+=`. For example:

```
prompt[i] += INTEGRAL_VALUE;
```

In your case it would be something like:

```
prompt[i] += offset[index];  // or [i % SIZE], depending on the desired semantics
```

This assumes offsets that will not overflow the `char` values in `prompt`. If overflow can occur, you should cast both `prompt [i]` and `offset[index]` to `unsigned char` to ensure the modulo arithmetic.

Comment: `prompt[i] = (unsigned(prompt[i]) + ARBITRARY_INTEGRAL_VALUE) % std::numeric_limits<char>::max()` to avoid UB...

Comment: actually, convert it to unsigned, I keep forgetting that. signed char overflow would be UB, if prompt[i]  is `char` increment may go sideways

Comment: @Swift Good point. While it's hard to say whether the OP's use case will lead to overflow, I've now amended the answer to warn of it.